# stdClass and type hinting

Tags: php

```
$obj = new stdClass();
echo gettype($obj); //object

function abc(object $obj) {
    return;
}

abc($obj); //Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to abc() must be an instance of object, instance of stdClass given
```

Why calling `abc($obj)` triggers error?

> Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to abc() must be an instance of object, instance of stdClass given

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Since PHP 5 (Jul 2004; Zend Engine 2) type hinting worked only for class and interface names, `array` ([PHP 5.1](https://www.php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.1.0); Nov 2005) or [`callable`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) ([PHP 5.4](https://www.php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.4.0); Mar 2012). There was no common ancestor `object` (like in some other programming languages like C#) in PHP object/type model. What you had to specify was `stdClass`

```
function abc(stdClass $obj) {
    return;
}
```

As of [PHP 7.2](https://php.net/manual/en/migration72.new-features.php) (Nov 2017) it's possible to use `object` type hint exactly as you guessed in your question:

```
function abc(object $obj) {
    return;
}
```

Cf. [*Type declarations* in the PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.declarations.php).

Comment: @Kirzilla: oh, didn't know about `callable`

Comment: `callable` would also allow you to pass a closure, which may or may not be what you're looking to allow.

Comment: This answer is now outdated.  Support for additional type hinting was added in [PHP 7](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php).

Comment: Pretty sure "not" was a typo.

Comment: I believe the use of type hinting 'object' has been deprecated in PHP 7.4

Answer (score 5):

Read the [documentation about type hinting in PHP](http://web.archive.org/web/20130401003628/http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php).
Your current code forces `abc` function to accept a parameter that is an instance of the class `object` (a class named `object`!).
Do that instead:

```
function abc(stdClass $obj)
```